# Programatically build UI for ListView's items

Tags: c++, uwp

From various questions, I know it is impossible to create `DataTemplate` from the code behind without using the `XamlReader`. So I want to ask if there is a way to programatically generates the UI for each Item in a `ListView`. I don't seem to find any relevant event handler or member of `ListView` for this purpose. Ideally, I want the `ListView` to invoke my handler code to generate UI for each data item it needs to display.

Comment: You can either generate UI and directly insert them into `ListViewItem`s; or you can still create your normal data templates, generate UI and place them within those templates.

Comment: @JustinXL I added an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imitating the official `XamlTreeView` sample, I have tried overriding some `ListView` method such as `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` but this won't work. The solution I found is as @JustinXL suggests: producing `ListViewItem` and insert them to the `ListView->Items` directly

```
//assume that items is a list of items we want to bind
myListView->Items->Clear();
for(auto i : items)
{
     ListViewItem^ v = ref new ListViewItem();
     v->Content = GenerateUIFor(i);
     myListView->Items->Append(v); // NOTE: a wrapping ListViewItem is required!
}
```

To support usual data binding, it would be best to make the data structure to cache the generated UI. For example,

```
ref class MyDataStructure
{
public:
    property ListViewItem^ Item
    {
        ListViewItem^ get()
        {
             if (_item == nullptr)
                 GenerateUI();
             return _item;
        }
    }
    void GenerateUI()
    {
        _item = ref new ListViewItem();
        _text_block = ref new TextBlock(); // sample
        _item->Content = _text_block;
        UpdateUI();
    }

    // Invoke this when changing the state of this object
    void UpdateUI()
    {
        if (_text_block != nullptr) // sample
        {
             _text_block->Text = this->ToString(); // sample
        }
    }
private:
    ListViewItem^ _item;
    TextBlock^ _text_block;
};
```

The downside of this is of course we can't make use of data virtualization. But it works properly for small set of data. For large set, one can use website's approach with *Next* and *Prev* button to load next page or go back to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

[ItemContainerGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcontainergenerator) should let you construct the entire UI for an item inside a list view. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be much in the way of non MSDN documentation/samples for this.

Alternatively if you can maintain a list of all the DataTemplates you might need to show, you could use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DataTemplateSelector) to choose which DataTemplate you want to show for each individual item.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is possible with `ItemContainerGenerator` given I have experimented with overriding some method. There is no way to set a customized object anyway.